# Detect other iPhones/iPads in the vicinity

Tags: iphone, ipad, detection

I am thinking about a web app to detect the presence of the other iPads/iPhones. This is purely theoretical at the moment, i have no idea how to do this.

My question is what is my best technology/language method of doing this?

Is it going to be bluetooth or gps? How does the App Bump work?

Thanks for any suggestions posted...

Comment: I would think bluetooth, but then the other iPhones/iPads would need to have bluetooth enabled as well.

Comment: This also wouldnt be possible in a browser would it?

Comment: actually @benhowdle89, javascript API allows you to specify that you want fine grain gps information and on my android that can get as accurate as 5m. http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html But you will not have access to Bluetooth from the browser, nor accelerometer information.

Answer (score 2):

Bump's FAQs: http://bu.mp/faq

According to their FAQs, when your phone has the Bump app up and ready, the app listens to the accelerometer for a sharp stop (your hand with your phone in it stopping when it hits the other person's hand with their phone in it), at this point, exact date time information as well as GPS position and characteristics of the bump are sent off to Bump's servers to compare other information from other bump users to see what other bump account shares most of that information. Bluetooth is not used in any capacity to make this happen, not for the transfer or the recognition of who to transfer to.

Your website may have to do the same thing. Have every instance report to your server, and then report back from the server where other people are.

Of course this goes without saying that I'm sure you were thinking about privacy settings and other layers of personal security.

Answer (score 1):

Options I'd explore:

- Bonjour discovery. In principle devices that can see each other via Bonjour could actually be in different continents, but usually it means 'same wireless network' and therefore at least 'same building'.
- Game kit. Actually, this either uses Bluetooth or the local network, so is probably going to have similar results to Bonjour discovery but in less code.

I wouldn't try location services like Core Location (actually I would, but only if the above don't work), as the results probably aren't going to be fine enough. Especially indoors: the Maps app on my phone places me in a circle of about 50 metres radius with my actual location being on the outer edge of said circle. Someone on the next street with similar resolution could, as far as the app is concerned, be adjacent to me.